# Can two verbs be kept in a sentence?

Tags: infinitives, clauses

If i write:

> Different rules `are enforced` ***to extract*** potential roof planes from classified data set.

then I feel there are 2 verbs in this sentence. So I modified it as:

> Different rules `are enforced` ***in order to extract*** potential roof planes from classified data set.

As I am using a phrase in order to extract, I feel this can not be considered as a verb.

*So, my question is which method is most suited?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay to have more than one verb in a sentence. Only one will be the main verb of the sentence (**are**, in this case), but extra verbs may appear inside clauses (subsentences within a full sentence) or in constructions like this one.

In your example, **to extract** is called an *infinitive*. Infinitives may be used in several ways, and in this sentence, the entire infinitive phrase **to extract potential roof planes from [the] classified data set** is an adverb, describing why the rules are enforced.

Adding **in order**, as in the second version, makes the reason a little more explicit, but both are correct and understandable.